# How to make a function template only works for types in a particular namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, namespaces

I have a namespace `my_space` and define a function template as

```
namespace my_space
{
    template<class T>
    ostream operator<<(ostream& os, T const& t)
    { ... }
}
```

I hope this function only works for my classes in `my_space`, or it may become ambiguous for some types not in `my_space`. For example

```
namespace my_space
{
     void f()
     {
           cout << "test"; //overload ambiguous
      }
}
```

Any way to avoid this?

Comment: For types not in `my_space`, your function won't be used if you write somethng like `other_type ot; std::cout << ot;`. Is it enough?

Comment: See the example

Comment: The short answer is to not overload an operator like that within your namespace.   As is, your code causes ambiguity, since it relies on `using namespace std` being in effect.   Remove that reliance (i.e. specify `ostream` fully as `std::ostream` within your namespace) completely.   Also, `operator<<()` functions that work with `std::ostream` return a reference - returning by value guarantees your code will not compile.

Comment: Typo here, and use std:: in original code.

Comment: @user1899020 I still can't get your question; it is ambiguous. http://rextester.com/JRGB3285

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with a bit of ADL (argument dependent lookup) and a helper function.

In this case, we use `namespace_test_helper`, and have it return `true_type` if and only if the type queried (or its dependent types) comes from `my_namespace`.

```
namespace support {
  template<class...Ts>
  constexpr std::false_type namespace_test_helper( Ts&&... ) { return {}; }
  template<class T>
  constexpr auto namespace_test( T&& t ) {
    return namespace_test_helper( std::forward<T>(t));
  }

}
namespace my_namespace {
  template<class T>
  constexpr std::true_type namespace_test_helper( T&& ) { return {}; }
  template<class T,
    class=std::enable_if_t<decltype(::support::namespace_test( std::declval<T>() )){}>
   >
  std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, T const& t ) {
    return os << "my <<";
  }
  enum bob {};
  void test() {
      std::cout << "hello world\n";
      std::cout << bob{} << "\n";
  }
}

int main() {
    ::my_namespace::test();
    std::cout << ::my_namespace::bob{} << "\n";
}
```

note that this will also be found by types with template arguments from within `my_namespace`.

We could extend this to detecting which of many namespaces something comes from; but you'd have to define a distinct type for each such namespace.  `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>` would work, but you are in charge of setting the unique `I` per namespace.